# Can't assign blockmatrix to a variable MAPLE

Tags: matrix, maple

http://puu.sh/ob1xV/ef7f8745d7.png 
Is there a way I can make S contain the result of

> linalg:-blockmatrix(2, 2, [a, b, b, a])

S := linalg:-blockmatrix(2, 2, [a, b, b, a]) doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out if this works for you

restart;

with(LinearAlgebra):

a:=RandomMatrix(4):

b:=RandomMatrix(4):

S:=`<<a|b>,<b|a>>`: